# python using pip package different than default one

Tags: python, pip

I would like to install a version of a python package that is newer than the one in the system.

The instructions describe how to do it with pip:

https://github.com/ewels/MultiQC

By running this command:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/ewels/MultiQC.git
```

Adding the `--user` flag does an installation, but when I try to see which is the default binary, it points to the older one which is available system-wide:

```
which multiqc
```

How do I call the one I just installed with `pip install --user URL`?

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The default place where pip will install the user copy is in:

```
$HOME/.local/bin/
```

Answer (score 0):

For any googlers - the trick is to get your own version of MultiQC to take preference over the system-wide version. The easiest way to do this is by *prepending* your personal installation directory to your `PATH`. So, taking the directory in the answer by @719016, you would add the following line to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin/:$PATH"
```

Apologies for the very late response. I'm the author of MultiQC and just found this post ;)